# List all the changes with contents from a specific user

Tags: perforce

I am trying to get the changes with diff from the changes from a specific user. once I know the change I can get the details using "p4 describe".

Do we have a way to get list of all the changes with contents from a specific user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `p4 changes -u USER` command to get the list of changes, then run "p4 describe" on each.

```
p4 -Ztag -F "describe %change%" changes -u USER | p4 -x - run
```

Comment: Note that this won't show the contents of added or deleted files.  It baffles me that `p4 describe` ignores them.

Comment: Use the "-du" flag to get unified (patch-compatible) format, which includes added/deleted files.

Comment: Is that new behavior in p4 2016.x or 2017.x? I am using 2015.1 (with a 2015.1 server), and `p4 describe -du CLN` does not include added/deleted files.

Comment: Hm, I was thinking of change #202956 (https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/user/relnotes.txt) but that only mentions the "diff" command -- might not work with describe.  Usually those flags behave the same across different commands but this might be a special case.

Comment: You guys really should just make `p4 describe -du` include added/deleted files if newer versions don't already do it.  It's a constant source of surprise.

Comment: Definitely worth logging a ticket with support if you haven't already!  I don't think anyone who's still at Perforce checks stackoverflow.  :)